# In Oracle, how do you change the 'default' database?

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I really should know this, but would someone tell me how to change the default database on Linux?

For example:

I have a database `test1` on `server1` with `ORACLE_SID=test1`. So, to connect to `test1` I can use:

```
sqlplus myuser/password
```

Connects to the default database, `test1`

I would now like the default sqlplus connection to go to database `test2` on server `server2`.

So, I've updated tnsnames so that the old `test1` entry now points to `test2@server2`. I've also added a separate entry for `test2` that points to the same place. However, the default connection still seems to go to `test1@server1`.

The following both work fine and go to database `test2` on `server2`:

```
sqlplus myuser/password@test1
sqlplus myuser/password@test2
```

But the default connection, `sqlplus myuser/password`, goes to `test1@server1`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume all of this is taking place on server1?

Comment: Yep. There are lots of legacy scripts on server1 that are started with "sqlplus user/pass". I'm trying to find a way to keep these scripts working following a database migration from server1 to server2.

Comment: Will the scripts ultimately run on server1 or server2? If server2, then all you need is to set ORACLE_SID on server2 to test2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on *kerchingo*'s answer: Oracle has multiple ways to identify a database.

The best way -- the one that you should always use -- is `USER/PASSWORD@SERVER`. This will use the Oracle naming lookup (tnsnames.ora) to find the actual server, which might be on a different physical host every time you connect to it. You can also specify an Oracle connection string as `SERVER`, but pretend you can't.

There are also two ways to specify a default server via environment variables. The first is `TWO_TASK`, which uses the naming lookup, and the second is `ORACLE_SID`, which assumes that the server is running on the current machine. `ORACLE_SID` takes precedence over `TWO_TASK`.

The reason that you should always use an explicit connect string is that you have no idea whether the user has set `TWO_TASK`, `ORACLE_SID`, both, or neither; nor do you know what they might be set to. Setting both to different values is a particularly painful problem to diagnose, particularly over the phone with a person who doesn't really understand how Oracle works (been there, done that).

Comment: Thanks very much. "TWO_TASK", which I've never come across before, is exactly what I need.

Comment: Hrm, [Ask Tom says](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:89412348059) that `TWO_TASK` overrides `ORACLE_SID`. For me on OS X, `TWO_TASK` works, but `ORACLE_SID` does not. Color me confused.

Comment: @theory - could be that the behavior changed (I haven't actively used Oracle since 8i), or it that my memory is incorrect (but that could never happen :-)). Not sure why `ORACLE_SID` isn't working for you, unless perhaps Oracle isn't listening on the standard port. Personally, I prefer `TWO_TASK` in all cases, but that's probably because I worked in an environment with lots of database servers.

Comment: @kdgregory: According to [this](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/sqlplus-connection-from-unix-with-and-without-the-oracle-sid,2) and [that](http://ora-exp.blogspot.com/2007/06/oraclesid-and-twotask-environment_21.html), `TWO_TASK` should override `ORACLE_SID`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're logged into server1, you'll need to connect to test2 using

```
sqlplus myuser/password@test2
```

because you have to go through a listener to get to server2. The string test2 identifies an entry in your tnsnames.ora file that specifies how to connect to test2. You won't be able to connect to a different server using the first form of your sqlplus command.

If both instances (test1, test2) were on server1, then you could, as @kerchingo states, set the ORACLE_SID environment variable to point at another instance.

Comment: That's a blow - looks like I've got some scripts to migrate.

Comment: No, see @kdgregrory's answer - export TWO_TASK=test2 should get you where you need to go.

Comment: Well - that's my new thing for the day - "TWO_TASK". Works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a enviroment variable `LOCAL` with the tns alias of your database.

```
> set LOCAL=test1
> sqlplus myuser/password
> ... connected to test1
> set LOCAL=test2
> sqlplus myuser/password
> ... connected to test2
```

This works on windows client, not shure about other os.

Comment: LOCAL is for Windows, TWO_TASK is for all others.  They do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The correct question is 'How do I change the default service'? Oracle DBMS offers two types of connection request: explicit and implicit. In an explicit request, you supply three operands like sqlplus username/password@service. In an implicit request, you ignore the third operand.

Implicit connection applies only when the client-host and server-host are the same. Consequently, the listener is on the same host.

The listener is the one that initially responds to connection request. In handling the implicit-connection request from the same host, 
it checks whether the instance name has been set. It checks the value of shell-variable ORACLE_SID.

If set, then it can handle implicit-connection request. Otherwise, it cannot, and you must perform explicit-connection request, supplying the third operand.

The listener-config file name listener.ora associates instance with service.
To change the default service you connect to, change the default value of instance.
Therefore, change the default value of shell-variable ORACLE_SID. You do it in the OS user config file such as .profile or similar config files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is set in your environment, can you echo $ORACLE_SID?